# How to force recyclerview to have dynamic height changing items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

Actually I'm trying to use `recyclerview` as a `viewpager` which is working fine by the help of `PagerSnapHelper()` class . But now the problem is how can I force `recyclerview` to change item heights dynamically and not show white space . Now when I try to load drawable pictures of two different sizes i.e a small and a bigger at first the smaller one is having correct size but when I scroll to next and then first some white space is shown below the `imageView`.You can see aforementioned problems in the given pictures.

[image: first image]  [image: second bigger image]  [image: white spaced first image]

**XML:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

**Recyclerview Items:**

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/recyclerImgView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
</FrameLayout>
```

**Adapter Code**:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Glide.with(ctx).load(pics.get(position)).into(holder.imageView);
}
```

**Activity Code:**

```
rView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    rView.setAdapter(adp);
    SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rView);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change image view width and height like below code..

```
<ImageView
```

android:id="@+id/recyclerImgView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />

and recycler view change height like below code..

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/rView"
android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
/>
```

add this below dependency into app level gradle file and give size is same all the device like below ..

```
  implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
```

Comment: thanks for your time sir but it's not changing anything

Comment: then give fixed height and width to image view .

Comment: also give image view height and width match_parent .it show full but image strach.

Comment: Actually I wanna change the view's height dynamically so that every image can be shown by it's original size . If I'll set any fixed size then my motto won't be accomplished.

Comment: add below dependency into app level gradle file and define height and width this format and i change put in my code.. implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4' . give size is same as all device..

Comment: android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"

Answer (score 0):

Change your Recyclerview Items with this code by adding scaleType in your image view

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp">

 <ImageView 
 android:id="@+id/recyclerImgView"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: no I can't give scaleType to fitXY it won't look good for all images

Comment: Then you can use centerCrop